# Crystal Report Viewer Error: This Group Section cannot be printed because its condition field is nonexistent or invalid

Tags: crystal-reports

i'm trying to print a report using cyrstal report but keep getting this error.
[image]

I wanna know where can i see the condition field that is non existent or invalid? It's so frustrating since I've already looked for solution online but none was applicable to the problem i've encountered

Answer (score 0):

If you Google this error message, you would find a detailed StackOverflow discussion.

Comment: I did googled it and found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867134/cr-error-the-group-section-cannot-be-printed-because-its-condition-field-is-none but it doesn't work with me.